# Extract list from a Future Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a future, that returns a Future response.

```
class FutureInformation extends StatelessWidget {

  const FutureInformation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 Future<List<SliderDetails>> getSliderDetails() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get((Uri.parse("/path/to/jsonFile.json")));
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            print(response.statusCode);
            var jsonData = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

      List<SliderDetails> listedFestivals = [];

      for (var map in jsonData) {

     SliderDetails allFestivals = SliderDetails(
     map['urlLink'] ?? "",
     map['name'] ?? "",
   );

  /// add them to the array
  listedFestivals.add(allFestivals);
  }
    return listedFestivals;
  }
  } catch (e){      
    print(e);
  }
      throw Exception('Nothing here, no food');
    }
```

my Json file only has 2 elements both strings

```
[{
  "image": "https://i.gyazo.com/5d808c6e55a8b2151974bf53b35e21b6.png",
  "title": "Yellow Car"
},
  {
    "image": "https://i.gyazo.com/7f33e4e78a54d1c4795aec5e0d57fab1.png",
    "title": "Black Car"
  },
  {
    "image": "https://i.gyazo.com/5e399b0ac1ffca12165f51af8bc3e81a.png",
    "title": "Blue Car"
  },
  {
    "image": "https://i.gyazo.com/8c74b2ec4da1ba477afbc67111573c4d.png",
    "title": "Vintage Car"
  }

]
```

From the response I want to create 2 different lists that would look like the example I have below.

```
final List<String> imgList = [
     "https://i.gyazo.com/5d808c6e55a8b2151974bf53b35e21b6.png",
      "https://i.gyazo.com/7f33e4e78a54d1c4795aec5e0d57fab1.png",
      "https://i.gyazo.com/5e399b0ac1ffca12165f51af8bc3e81a.png",
      "https://i.gyazo.com/8c74b2ec4da1ba477afbc67111573c4d.png",        

    ];

final List<String> titlesList = [
      "Yellow Car",
      "Black Car",
      "Blue Car",
      "Vintage Car",
      
    ];
```

The response I get is

```
Instance of 'Future<List<SliderDetails>>'
```

And what  I want to know how can I split the future into 2 separate lists, thanks for any help.

This is how I am calling the Future

```
var datasource = const FutureInformation();

    getSliderDetailsEvents() async {
      List futureEvents = await datasource.getSliderDetails();
      return futureEvents ;
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: use `await getSliderDetails()`

Comment: Added where I call the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first change your `SliderDetails` model to this:

```
class SliderDetails {
  final List<String> links;
  final List<String> names;
  SliderDetails({required this.links, required this.names});
}
```

then change your `getSliderDetails` to this:

```
Future<SliderDetails> getSliderDetails() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get((Uri.parse("/path/to/jsonFile.json")));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.statusCode);
        var jsonData = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

        List<String> urlLinks = [];
        List<String> names = [];

        for (var map in jsonData) {
          urlLinks.add(map['urlLink'] ?? "");
          names.add(map['name'] ?? "");
        }
        return SliderDetails(
          links: urlLinks,
          names:names,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    throw Exception('Nothing here, no food');
  }
```

now you can use it like this:

```
getSliderDetailsEvents() async {
  SliderDetails futureEvents = await datasource.getSliderDetails();
  
  print("links:${futureEvents.links}");
  print("links:${futureEvents.names}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now you can receive a `Future<List<SliderDetails>>` because you are now awaiting the response from your `Future` method.

So you should add the keywords `await` and `async` to await the response from your `Future` method. (In you case probably a missing await in getSliderDetails).
That will give you a `List<SliderDetails>` instead of a `Future<List<SliderDetails>>`

To separate your current `List<SliderDetails>` into two separate `List`
You can use multiple methods to iterate on your list and add some logic.

I recommend using the `map` method on `List`.

```dart
    final List<String> imageList = futureEvents.map((e) => e["image"]).toList();
    final List<String> titleList = futureEvents.map((e) => e["title"]).toList();
```